# How to set sslmode as allow in postgresql in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, postgresql

I used the following code to connect to the postgresql database. It works good. But now I want to connect it with sslmode enabled. Can anyone help me to acheive this.

```
NSString* portS = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:port].stringValue;

headerPG = PQsetdbLogin(serverName.UTF8String,portS.UTF8String,NULL,NULL,databaseName.UTF8String,
                        userName.UTF8String, password.UTF8String);

BOOL result = [self connected];
NSString *resultString;
if(!result){
    //Error connection
    [self errorPG];
    resultString = @"Connection Failed";
}
else{
    resultString = @"Connected Successfully";
}
return resultString;
```

I dont know how to use the following function.

```
PGconn *PQconnectdbParams(const char **keywords, const char **values, int expand_dbname);
```

How to feed data in keywords, values, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer myself.

```
const char *const keywords[] = {[@"sslmode" UTF8String], [@"hostaddr" UTF8String], [@"port" UTF8String], [@"user" UTF8String], [@"password" UTF8String], [@"dbname" UTF8String]};
    const char *const values[] = {[@"allow" UTF8String], [serverName UTF8String], [portS UTF8String],[userName UTF8String],[password UTF8String],[databaseName UTF8String]};

    headerPG = PQconnectdbParams(keywords, values, 1);
```

Here the `keyword` array has the keywords of postgresql and `value` array has the values of particular key in keyword array.